# I have line strings in points and need to conver them to lon/lat degrees

Tags: postgis, convert, coordinate-system

I need to convert line strings back to latitude & longitude coordinates.

Here are is an example, please keep in mind that they do NOT reference the same point. I have included the values to illustrate the differences between the way points are stored in PostGIS and what I need, which is the values in degrees.

Example:
The data used to expresses a point in QGIS looks something like...
663821.19 1185061.15

I want to convert it to degrees so it looks some thing like this...
10.679080000 -61.507780000

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To project correctly, you need to know the coordinate system of the original data. What was the projection of the original data? Do you want a SQL query to project and create a new layer in PostGIS itself? or do you need something else?

Comment: The function you should look for is ST_Tranform in PostGIS

Comment: The coordinate system of the original data is WGS 84 UTM 20 North. What I need is to convert the Line strings (Roads & Streets) to line strings of longitude latitude, longitude latitude, longitude latitude, etc... So I can import them into Gisgraphy

Answer (score 1):

To do this simply, all you need to do is change the projection.

You can probably do this straight in PostGIS by doing a select and specifying the coordinate system, but I'll outline how to do it in QGIS.

1. Load the layer in QGIS and ensure that the projection is defined, if it is not defined, define it (if you don't know what projection it is look for metadata or talk to someone who you got the data from)
2. Save the layer out of QGIS by right clicking on the layer and choosing 'save as' then specifying your target projection (looks like lat, lon, so perhaps WGS84 would do you).